# Keep UL visible when hovering from div to UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a custom header / nav where I have two elements that represent two sections of a website. I want to be able to hover over one of the elements and display a particular menu. However the Menu list isn't a child of the element. So I can't do it with CSS.

The problem i'm having is when I hover over the element, the menu shows. But I move my mouse to hover over the menu and and as soon as move away from the element the menu disappears. I have tried adding a `display:block` to the manu items, with a `.delay()` method running but there is still a slight flicker when  moving the mouse away from the div.

Here is my current code:

//HTML

```
<header>

    <a class='hoverOverOne'>Hover over me to show menu</a>
    <a class='hoverOverTwo'>Hover over me to show menu</a>

    <nav>

<ul id='menuToShow-One'>
<li>testing</li>
<li>testing</li>

</ul>

<ul id='menuToShow-Two'>
    <li>testing</li>
    <li>testing</li>
</ul>

</nav>
</header>
```

// jQuery

```
jQuery("a.hoverOverOne").hover(
      function () {
         jQuery('#menuToShow-One').slideDown('medium').delay(500);
      }, 
      function () {
         jQuery('#menuToShow-One').slideUp('medium').delay(500);
    });

    jQuery("a.country").hover(
      function () {
         jQuery('#menuToShow-Two').slideDown('medium').delay(500);
      }, 
      function () {
         jQuery('#menuToShow-Two').slideUp('medium').delay(500);
    });
```

// CSS

```
#menuToShow-One{
display:none;
}

#menuToShow-Two{
display:none;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: First - typo in your anchor links, those hrefs should be classes according to your CSS and JS. Second -- you've painted yourself into a corner here, can you explain why the dropdowns can't be children of the hover elements?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Updated the a tags. They are now classes. It's because the a tags, are inside a div. It's because they are Images. The Wrapper they are inside is 100% Where as the nav isn't. It's hard to explain without showing the design.

Comment: There are ways to attack that with CSS (such as positioned elements and width declarations). You might consider posting the whole enchilada and reconsidering the architecture on this header.

Comment: I know what you are saying, but it's not possible with how the design is put together. It's a responsive site, plus the nav can't be absolute positioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
 $("a.hoverOverOne, a.hoverOverTwo").hover(function () {
  var menu = '#menu'+this.id;
        $('.menu').not(menu).slideUp(0);
        $(menu).slideDown('medium');
    });
 $("ul.menu").mouseleave(function () {
  $(this).slideUp('medium');
    });
});
```

```css
a.hoverOverOne{
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#menuToShow-One{
  display:none;
}
#menuToShow-Two{
  display:none;
}
nav{
  display:inline-block;
}
ul li{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <a class='hoverOverOne' id="ToShow-One">Hover over me to show menu 1</a>
 <a class='hoverOverTwo' id="ToShow-Two">Hover over me to show menu 2</a><br />
 <nav>
  <ul id='menuToShow-One' class="menu">
   <li>testing menu 1</li>
   <li>testing menu 1</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id='menuToShow-Two' class="menu">
   <li>testing menu 2</li>
   <li>testing menu 2</li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: This seems to work really well, but I can't apply a data attribute as it's part of a drupal module im editing.

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer, i apologies, it had been a long day. I do have access to the a tag. I've added the data-attribute and it worked perfectly. However, when I mouse off of the menu's it stays visible. Is it possible to hide it when you move the mouse back off any of the elements?

Comment: What do u mean by "any of the elements"??

Comment: Sorry I mean any of the menu items, so when you remove your cursor away from the menu, it could disappear.

Comment: Yup.. Update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Check the following solution.  No need for JS to power this one.

```css
#hover-one:hover ~ nav ul#menuToShow-One,
#hover-two:hover ~ nav ul#menuToShow-Two {
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#menuToShow-One,
#menuToShow-Two {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav:hover #menuToShow-One,
nav:hover #menuToShow-Two {
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>

  <a id="hover-one" href='#hoverOverOne'>Hover over me to show menu</a>
  <a id="hover-two" href='#hoverOverTwo'>Hover over me to show menu</a>

  <nav>

    <ul id='menuToShow-One'>
      <li>testing 1</li>
      <li>testing 1</li>

    </ul>

    <ul id='menuToShow-Two'>
      <li>testing 2</li>
      <li>testing 2</li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
</header>
```